# How to find words with same characters or ANY of the special characters repeated continuously (3+ times)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find and replace words with `' '` for 2 different queries

1. Find and replace words which have the **same** character repeated more than 3 times **continuously**

**OR**

2. Find and replace words which have **any** special Characters repeated 3 or more times continuously.

Looking at the below query:

```
re.findall(r'([a-zA-Z])\1{3,}', 'I doono if HELLO && AA+-AA should be here but hellllooooo or Whyyy should definitely be. So should ++, x+=-y  --- ')
```

it gives the alphabet repeated where it should be  `['hellllooooo', 'Whyyy', '++,' , 'x+=-y', '---']`

and

```
re.findall(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]{3,}', 'I doono if HELLO should be here but hellllooooo or Whyyy should be here. So should ++, x+=-y  --- ')
```

gives almost accurate results except `x+=-y` is given as `+=-`

**So after applying these two conditions, the final result looks like:**

`I doono if HELLO && AA+-AA should be here but or should definitely be. So should`

Comment: By "special characters", do you mean any characters that are not alphanumeric?

Comment: @WaisKamal Yes. `[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\t\n]`

Comment: Would you like to replace the whole word containing the repeated tokens, or just the repeated tokens? It would be much better to give examples in the form of input/desired output.

Comment: The word. Thereisn't any which has same repeated characters more than 3 times. It must be a typo or OCR error.

Comment: Strictly speaking, "words" cannot contain special chars and `++,` and `x+=-y` are not "words". In this regard, it is important to define word boundaries. So, what are they here? Whitespaces?

Answer (score 1):

For the example given in the question, replacing all matches of the regular expression

```
(?=\w*(\w)\1{2})\w*|(?=[^ ]*[+,=')-]{3})[^ ]+
```

with a single space (`' '`) results in the following string:

```
"I doono if HELLO && AA+-AA should be here but   or   should definitely be. So should        "
```

As "special characters" were not defined in the question I assumed them to be those in the string `+,=')-`. That could be easily changed, of course.

The resulting string is not quite what was asked for, in that a space was added for every match and no spaces were removed, but it appears to me to be consistent with the stated replacement rules.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/885khn/1)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(?=            # begin a positive lookahead
  \w*(\w)      # match >= 0 characters followed by a word character,
               # the latter being saved to capture group 1
  \1{2}        # match the character in capture group 1 twice
)              # end positive lookahead
\w*            # match >= 0 word characters (will be >= 3)
|              # or
(?=            # begin a positive lookahead
  [^ ]*        # match >= 0 characters other than spaces
  [+,=')-]{3}  # match three special characters
)              # end positive lookahead
[^ ]*          # match >= 0 characters other than spaces (will be >= 3)
```

`(?=\w*(\w)\1{2})` forces the following string of word characters to contain a word character repeated (at least) three times in a row.

`(?=[^ ]*[+,=')-]{3})` forces the following string of non-space characters to contain three special characters in a row.

---

If desired, the extra spaces can be removed by modifying the regular expression slightly and replacing matches with empty strings:

```
(?=\w*(\w)\1{2})\w* *|(?=[^ ]*[+,=')-]{3,})[^ ]+ *
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fOZGvI/1)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to consider any one or more non-whitespace chunks as "words". In these cases, it is much easier to work with lists obtained with `text.split()`, filter out those items that do not match the regex and then join the list back with a space:

```py
import re
text = 'I doono if HELLO && AA+-AA should be here but hellllooooo or Whyyy should definitely be. So should ++, x+=-y  --- '
rx = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z])\1{2,}|[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]{3,}')
print( " ".join(x for x in text.split() if not rx.search(x)) )
# => I doono if HELLO && AA+-AA should be here but or should definitely be. So should
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/CfFs0t). The regex is simple:

- `([a-zA-Z])\1{2,}` - an ASCII letter and then two or more occurrences of the same letter
- `|` - or
- `[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]{3,}` - three or more chars other than ASCII letters, digits and any whitespace chars.

The `" ".join(x for x in text.split() if not rx.search(x))` part splits the `text` with whitespaces (`text.split()`), removes all chunks that do not match the regex (`if not rx.search(x)`) and joins back to a string (with `" ".join(...)`).

Comment: Good solution, perhaps not for the question as stated, but for what the OP probably wants to actually do.